# Yii2: ротатор баннеров

Tags: php, yii2

Мне нужно на сайте сделать ротатор баннеров. То есть, на одно место клиент ставит 3 баннера и говорит: 1-й - 20%, 2-й - 30%, 3-й - 50%. Понятно, что чаще всего будет показываться 3-й баннер. Только как это правильно просчитать? Может есть готовый плагин?

Если кто делать - поделитесь соображениями, куда копать

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко, то алгоритм может выглядеть так.

```
$b[1] = ['rate' => 20, 'title' => 'title1', 'url' => 'url1'];
$b[2] = ['rate' => 30, 'title' => 'title2', 'url' => 'url2'];
$b[3] = ['rate' => 50, 'title' => 'title3', 'url' => 'url3'];

$show = $b[1];
$rand = random_int(1, 100);

foreach($b as $k => $v){
    if($rand >= $v['rate']){
        continue;
    }

    $show = $b[$k];
}
```